# I can't match a simple username with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

It's very simple:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(username, @"/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (!match.Success)
    throw new Exception("Manglende/ugyldig brukernavn.");
```

But no matter what it fails that test. What am I forgetting?

Comment: It would be nice if we could actually see what `username` is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't put slashes around the regex:

```
@"^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$"
```

The slashes are typically used in other languages to delimit a regex. But in C#, the entire string is the pattern so additional delimiters are not required.

Comment: What I get for copypastein'. Approved in 11 mins

Comment: @nneonneo IMHO, a little bit explanation would be better for OP and who find this answer on internet why they shouldn't use slashes..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `/ /` in a .net regex.

Comment: as far as we *all* know now, after nneonneo's answer

Comment: @ceth Writing this answer takes 3 minutes? :)